# Mouse Event Didn't Work In RadToolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, mouseevent

I have a radtoolbar with two buttons inside, and one of buttons has Mouse Enter event which changes the background of button. but didn't work and the button will not change

what's the problem?

toolbar component:

```
<telerik:RadToolBar x:Name="radToolbar" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False" Height="30" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Width="75"/>
        <telerik:RadButton x:Name="mybutton" Content="Button" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Width="60" MouseEnter="mybutton_MouseEnter">

        </telerik:RadButton>
    </telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Mouse event:

```
private void mybutton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.mybutton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 20, 50, 200));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RadToolBar` has a number of predefined styles for the common controls that can be included in the tool bar, overriding any explicit changes to the style that is made in XAML or via code.

A dramatic way to illustrate this behavior is to remove **all** the predefined styles using this change to your code:

```
<telerik:RadToolBar x:Name="radToolbar" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False" Height="30" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadToolBar">
            <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyleSelector" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadToolBar.Resources>
    <Button Content="Button" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Width="75"/>
    <telerik:RadButton x:Name="mybutton" Content="Button" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Width="60" MouseEnter="mybutton_MouseEnter" >
     </telerik:RadButton>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

Your code should now work with the likely side-effect that other parts of the styling will need to be added back in by yourself (quite a big job!).

Various techniques to applying styles to the controls in the `RadBarTool` are discussed in this [Telerik forum thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/can-t-restyle-radbutton-in-radtoolbar), and a link is given to a [Telerik SDK demo](https://github.com/telerik/xaml-sdk/tree/master/ToolBar/ToolBarCustomStyledElements) here.